# Android LinearGradient and weird relative positioning

Tags: android, layout, gradient

I have the following code with a LinearGradient, which looks much the same as all the other examples out there.

```
public class CustomColourBar extends View
{

public CustomColourBar( Context context, AttributeSet attribs )
{
    super( context, attribs );
}    

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    setMeasuredDimension(170, 40);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
{
    int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();

    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(
        0, 0, 0, height, 
        Color.RED, Color.YELLOW,
        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP );

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setShader(shader);
    RectF fgRect = new RectF( 0, 0, width, height);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(fgRect, 7f, 7f, paint);

}
}
```

In a layout, this produces the following, which is just about correct:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqbx1.png]

However, when other things change the Y position of my view, it goes wrong:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyeU.png]

The LinearGradient is using the absolute position relative to the topmost view (i.e. the dialog). I can't for the life of me figure out - why?

Thank you!

Rob

Comment: I've given up on this and now use ninepatch graphics (which have a gradient). My graphics are white, so I also borrowed some code to do a 'colorize' filter which gives me colour control. 

I found that all gradients (radial and the one I've forgotten) behaved in the same way, and I could see no activity/layout agnostic way to make them work. Even retrieving and using the position on screen didn't help - worked fine on one configuration but not others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. Positions in the shader are not shape but canvas relative.

Therefore you need to draw your shapes on the canvas always around the origo and translate the canvas with the desired position.

For instance:

DO NOT:

```
canvas.drawCircle(posx, posy, radius);
```

DO:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(posx, posy);
canvas.drawCircle(0,0,radius);
canvas.restore();
```

Hope it helped! ;)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will find the code in question and review the fix, then accept your answer, though be warned it may not be immediately!

Comment: A little bit unintuitive that we have to move the whole canvas to draw a gradient somewhere, but once you know how it works it's simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the android manifest file, choose the activity you are using and make sure configChanges property of it has orientation ticked

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid - I tried to no avail, but this is also meant to be a generic View component that shouldn't force such changes on the using activity. I've discounted any layout changes too for the same reason.